# eurl.axd webresource.axd scriptresource axd not found errors IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I have recently started getting these errors:

```
eurl.axd webresource.axd scriptresource axd not found errors IIS6.
```

IIS logs show **file not found error**.

The website is very slow.

Has anybody faced this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your global.asax in Application_Error try to log the offending url and find out which control is causing it.

```
((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request.Url
```

[File Not Found Exception Application Error](http://technobird.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/file-not-found-exception-in.html)